# Bitcoin-qt Not Syncing with errors

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-core, synchronization, ubuntu, error

My bitcoin-qt (on ubuntu installed via the PPA) just plain won't sync. It's been running for days and no/little progress past ~82256 blocks remaining...

I've also got an error displaying "Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct! You may need to upgrade, or other nodes may need to upgrade."

I've got a good unrestricted internet connection and plenty of RAM, CPU and HDD.

I even tried loading the client with instructions on here (bootstrapping)  http://eu2.bitcoincharts.com/blockchain/ to no end.

I've also purged all files from the .bitcoin directory (excluding wallet.dat of course) and started again to no end.

Can someone help?

```
{
"version" : 80100,
"protocolversion" : 70001,
"walletversion" : 60000,
"balance" : 0.00000000,
"blocks" : 149874,
"connections" : 11,
"proxy" : "",
"difficulty" : 1468195.42722083,
"testnet" : false,
"keypoololdest" : 1337298958,
"keypoolsize" : 100,
"paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
"unlocked_until" : 0,
"errors" : "Warning: Displayed transactions may not be correct! You may need to upgrade, or other nodes may need to upgrade."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try starting with the `-reindex` command-line flag. That will rebuild the database on disk (as it seems corrupted), without redownloading the blocks you already have.

It's strange that wiping your datadir didn't help though.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the bitcoin-qt client from the https://www.weusecoins.com/en/getting-started website after purging the install from the PPA.

It all works fine now. Think it was a bad client.

Comment: After a few days of working fine, the error is back. I'll look into this and get back to you.

Comment: I've found a forum that shines some light on the subject. I'm running "-checkblocks=0 -checklevel=6" now, we'll see how that goes. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=103167.0

Comment: Seems to start working and then simply dies. I think it might have something to do with my encrypted file-system.